# How do you format the following timestamp to readable string in Android?

Tags: android, timestamp

My app pulls an article from a website that has the following timestamp structure:

> 2017-04-25T00:00:00-05:00

How do I convert it to a format that would read:

```
April 25, 2017 12:00 AM
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, it can help you do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the Timestamp to format a String, like:

```
SimpleDateFormat smDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm");
String dateString = smDateFormat.format([timestamp]);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried myself doing this...

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

SimpleDateFormat smDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.US);
String dateString = smDateFormat.format(timestamp);

Toast.makeText(this, dateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

...and the output is:

[image: Example output]

Comment: That didn't work.  Got the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:302)

Comment: If you still need it, check the edit, it was maybe the 'hh' or 'd' instead of 'HH' and 'dd', but I don't really think so

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, but here is the solution with which I created:

```
public static String convertADevotionTimestamp(String time){
        String year = time.substring(0,4);
        String month = time.substring(5,7);
        String date = time.substring(8,10);
        String hour = time.substring(11,13);
        String minute = time.substring(14,16);

        // Format month
        int monthNum = Integer.parseInt(month);
        String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        month = months[monthNum - 1];

        // Format AM vs PM
        String amOrPm = null;
        int hourNum = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        if (hourNum >= 12){
            amOrPm = "pm";
            hour = String.valueOf(hourNum - 12);
        } else {
            amOrPm = "am";
            if (hourNum == 0){
                hour = "12";
            }
        }

        return month + " " + date + ", " + year + " at " + hour + ":" + minute + amOrPm + " ET";
    }
```